# How to change the color of visited anchor link in java script dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a problem in Dom. I want to change the color of a visited link on the basis of `alreadyRead` (a Boolean). I am new in this field so if I am doing any wrong please forgive me for that. Here is my code snippet. Thanks in advance!

```
var books = [
  {
    title: 'The Design of EveryDay Things',
    author: 'Don Norman',
    alreadyRead: false
  },
  {
    title: 'The Most Human Human',
    author: 'Brian Christian',
    alreadyRead: true
  }
];

var appHandle = document.getElementById('app');
var ulTag = document.createElement('ul')
books.forEach(book =>{
  if(book.alreadyRead === true){
    document.linkcolor="green"
  } else{
    document.linkcolor ="red"
  }
  var liTag = document.createElement('li');
  var navList =document.createTextNode(`${book.title} by ${ book.author}`)
  var aTag = document.createElement('a')
  aTag.setAttribute('href','#');
  aTag.appendChild(navList)
  liTag.appendChild(aTag);
  ulTag.appendChild(liTag);
})
appHandle.appendChild(ulTag)
```

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, you could achieve what you seem to want with the following line:

```
aTag.classList.toggle('alreadyRead', book.alreadyRead);
```

This line uses the `Element.classList` API to toggle the `alreadyRead` class-name on the relevant `aTag` element node, based on the switch that follows the class-name. If the switch returns `true` the class is added (if not already present) or if the switch returns `false` the class-name is removed (if present).

```js
var books = [{
    title: 'The Design of EveryDay Things',
    author: 'Don Norman',
    alreadyRead: false
  },

  {
    title: 'The Most Human Human',
    author: 'Brian Christian',
    alreadyRead: true

  }
];

var appHandle = document.getElementById('app');
var ulTag = document.createElement('ul')
books.forEach(book => {
  var liTag = document.createElement('li');
  var navList = document.createTextNode(`${book.title} by ${ book.author}`);
  var aTag = document.createElement('a')
  aTag.setAttribute('href', '#');
  aTag.appendChild(navList)
  liTag.appendChild(aTag);
  ulTag.appendChild(liTag);
  
  aTag.classList.toggle('alreadyRead', book.alreadyRead);
})
appHandle.appendChild(ulTag)
```

```css
.alreadyRead {
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4v9h7ofy/).

References:

- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).